# Array to JSON encoding odd behaviour with hebrew characters

Tags: php, mysql, json, encoding, utf-8

So the story goes, I'm trying to save a JSON string to my database, but every Hebrew letter is transforming into "\u05d4" for example, which supposed to be the letter "He" in Hebrew (ה).

**English is encoded properly**

I've done my research and found that this encoding is JAVA or C/C++ character encoding, but I can't find a way to store it in my database as regular UTF-8 character for editing convenience...

Fetching the data and showing it on my pages works well(in Hebrew, as it should) but no matter what functions I try to throw at the problem, the data in my database is encoded...

**Example:**

```
\u05d0\u05d9\u05e4\u05d4 \u05ea\u05e8\u05e6\u05d4 \u05e9\u05d4\u05e9\u05dd \u05d9\u05de\u05d5\u05e7\u05dd?
```

is supposed to be:

```
איפה תרצה שהשם ימוקם?
```

As you can see, the encoding also takes up a lot of extra space, and editing from phpMyAdmin is impossible...

my functions to save the data:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($pinfo))
```

while $pinfo contains all of the data in array(which is encoded in utf-8)

Is it a problem with JSON_ENCODE() or something else completely that I'm not aware of yet?

**EDIT**

Using the information given by Álvaro González and Tanuel Mategi, I was able to find the solution I was after:
`mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($pinfo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))`

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are using mysql or mysqli? Please share full code.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly why you're using json_encode() there?

Comment: This is correct behaviour. your hebrew characters are getting escaped to unicode blocks. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block. if you use `json_decode()` they should be decoded again.

Comment: I'm using mysqli, and the code is very long and not really relevant... I'm using JSON_ENCODE to save many variables data to a database as text so I wouldn't need to create hundreds of columns in my database. I was able to reach a solution using your help, edited with the solution above! Thanks!

Comment: json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) works well for inserting Hebrew string into MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u05d4` is a perfectly valid escape sequence in JSON. It corresponds to the [U+05d4 Unicode character](http://unicode-table.com/en/05D4/) (Hebrew Letter He). There's apparently nothing wrong in your JSON output—I think you just misread the [format documentation](http://json.org/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
Using the information you gave, I found a solution to my problem:
`mres(json_encode($pinfo, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE))`

Comment: I would have said you didn't have a problem in the first place... :)

Comment: Correct, shall say a solution to my inconvenience!

Answer (score 0):

I use `json_encode($x)`, no second arg.  And `json_decode($y, TRUE)`.  Consider that combination.

If by `mres`, you mean `mysql_real_escape_string()`, always use an escaping function.

But do *not* use `mysql_*`; switch to `PDO` or `mysqli_*`.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the result, when you decode it again you will get exact the result that you want..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I wrote that I needed regular (not encoded) text for editing convenience on PhpMyAdmin